# Check for duplicates of values, Excel VBA to Access?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2016

I'm attempting to add information to an .accdb from an Excel worksheet but want first to compare one value to make certain it doesn't already exist in the table, and if so, skip it and move on to the next row. The add information portion of the code works when I don't try to verify that it doesn't already exists, but I can't get the comparison to. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
Sub UploadData()

Dim con As Object, cmd As Object, rst As Object
Dim Path As String
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim L As Range
Dim LT As Long, LC As Long, R As Long
Dim D1 As Date, D2 As Date

Dim PRODL As Integer, TNAME As Integer, CName As Integer, VNAME As Integer, ACTNO As Integer, SOURC As Integer, BATID As Integer, BILID As Integer
Dim CONDT As Integer, BILDT As Integer, DUEDT As Integer, BEGDT As Integer, ENDDT As Integer, PRBAL As Integer, CCHRG As Integer, IMGLC As Integer

Dim i As Integer, Lcol As Integer, LRow As Integer
Dim Calc As Double, CL As Double, CW As Double
Dim Z As String

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection"): Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command"): Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet"):
Path = Sheets("AuditTool").Range("B2").Value

Set WS = Worksheets("TestBed")
With WS
    Lcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

PRODL = 0
TNAME = 0
CName = 0
VNAME = 0
ACTNO = 0
SOURC = 0
BATID = 0
BILID = 0
CONDT = 0
BILDT = 0
DUEDT = 0
BEGDT = 0
ENDDT = 0
PRBAL = 0
CCHRG = 0
IMGLC = 0


For i = 1 To Lcol
    Z = LCase(WS.Cells(1, i).Value)
    If Z = "productline" Then
        PRODL = i
    End If
    If Z = "teamname" Then
        TNAME = i
    End If
    If Z = "clientname" Then
        CName = i
    End If
    If Z = "vendor" Then
        VNAME = i
    End If
    If Z = "accountnumber" Then
        ACTNO = i
    End If
    If Z = "billreceiptmethod" Then
        SOURC = i
    End If
    If Z = "idbatch" Then
        BATID = i
    End If
    If Z = "idbill" Then
        BILID = i
    End If
    If Z = "consolidationcreatedon" Then
        CONDT = i
    End If
    If Z = "billdate" Then
        BILDT = i
    End If
    If Z = "pastduedate" Then
        DUEDT = i
    End If
    If Z = "begindate" Then
        BEGDT = i
    End If
    If Z = "enddate" Then
        ENDDT = i
    End If
    If Z = "previousbalance" Then
        PRBAL = i
    End If
    If Z = "currentcharges" Then
        CCHRG = i
    End If
    If Z = "imagelocation" Then
        IMGLC = i
    End If
Next i    

With WS
    Set L = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
    LC = L.Row
End With
If LC < 2 Then
    LC = 2
End If
LT = LC - 1 'count bill IDs

con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Path & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
con.ConnectionTimeout = 0: con.CommandTimeout = 0: con.Open: cmd.CommandTimeout = 0: Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con

R = 2

On Error Resume Next

With WS
    Do While .Cells(R, 2) <> ""

        AdHocID = 0
        rst.Open "SELECT [ID] FROM AdHocReport WHERE (BillID = " & WS.Cells(R, BILID).Value & ")", con, 1, 3
        AdHocID = rst![ID]

        With rst
            If AdHocID = 0 Then
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            .Fields("BillID") = WS.Cells(R, BILID).Value
            .Fields("ProductLine") = WS.Cells(R, PRODL).Value
            .Fields("TxName") = WS.Cells(R, TNAME).Value
            .Fields("CxName") = WS.Cells(R, CName).Value
            .Fields("VxName") = WS.Cells(R, VNAME).Value
            .Fields("AcctNo") = WS.Cells(R, ACTNO).Value
            .Fields("Source") = WS.Cells(R, SOURC).Value
            .Fields("BatchID") = WS.Cells(R, BATID).Value
            .Fields("ConsolidationDate") = WS.Cells(R, CONDT).Value
            .Fields("BillDate") = WS.Cells(R, BILDT).Value
            .Fields("DueDate") = WS.Cells(R, DUEDT).Value
            .Fields("BeginDate") = WS.Cells(R, BEGDT).Value
            .Fields("EndDate") = WS.Cells(R, ENDDT).Value
            .Fields("PreviousBalance") = WS.Cells(R, PRBAL).Value
            .Fields("CCharges") = WS.Cells(R, CCHRG).Value
            .Fields("ImgLoc") = WS.Cells(R, IMGLC).Value
            '    .Fields("SumAcctNo") = WS.Cells(2, SUMAC).Value
            .Update
            R = R + 1
            Else
            R = R + 1
            End If
        End With
    Loop
End With

MsgBox LT & " Bill IDs Successfully Uploaded"

rst.Close
con.Close

WS.UsedRange.ClearContents

End Sub
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing the check in the right order. The way it is written, it detects the first duplicate and skips the insert, but the AdHocID value never changes. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: You can't add a multi-field record to a single-field recordset. Instead of selecting only the ID, select all the fields you'd need to add and then check rst.EOF to see if there's no existing record.

Comment: Would also be helpful to remove the `On Error Resume Next` and try to fix any errors, or you may end up inserting bad/missing data.

Comment: This project got back-burner'd but is on the flames again. I commented out the error suppression and cleaned a few things up, but even using .EOF and Using "Select * FROM AdHocReport..." I'm not catching the duplicates. Any other ideas? TIA!